# What is the order for watching the Gintama series?

Tags: gintama

I wanted to try *Gintama* for a long time but I have no idea as to the order in which I have to watch it.

What is the order for watching the anime series?

Answer (score 9):

Here is one possible viewing order taken from [Gintama Reddit FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/Gintama/comments/6j6g66/gintama_animemanga_faqs_and_gintama_discord_server/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=usertext&utm_name=Gintama&utm_content=t1_dk89n24)

> **What is the watch order of the series?**
>
> Skip episodes 1 and 2. They were a special to celebrate the series getting animated.
>
> Gintama: 3-201 (The arc at eps 58-61 was made into a movie. Watch it if you don't care about spoilers, instead of the the arc in the series.)
>
> Gintama Movie 1: Benizakura (the Benizakura arc in eps 58-61). CANON MOVIE
>
> Gintama'(2011): 202-252
>
> Gintama' Enchousen: 253-265 (with some reruns in the middle)
>
> Gintama Movie 2: Be Forever Yorozuya CANON MOVIE. This movie was made to signify the end of the series, as they didn't know if it would continue (but it did).
>
> Gintama° (2015): 266-316
>
> Gintama. (2017): 317-328
>
> Gintama. "Porori": 329-342
>
> Gintama. Silver Soul Arc: 343-Ongoing
>
> EDIT: Gintama End-Game starts at episode 300. Everything passed there is part of the "conclusion" of the series. Contains heavy spoilers.

Comment: As of today, Gintama ended at episode `367`. Then there are 2 web movies called "Gintama: The Semi-Final" and the last movie called "Gintama: The Final". https://anidb.net/anime/11850/relation/graph